# Magento Connect not working (shows magento installation)

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

There is a strage problem in my website's magento connect feature. Whenever I will click on Magento Connect, it will show me the installation page of magento.

The url is something like this
http://www.mystore.com/downloader/?return=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.saletab.com%2Findex.php%2Fadmin_panel%2F

Is this because someone changed core file? Or because I am ruining magento 1.7 and 1.8 is released?

Please note that another instance, of the EXACT same code and database works fine when I click on magento connect, but not this one.

Please tell me how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Did you check logs files for errors ?

Comment: have checked clearing cache and session from your installation directory

Comment: It looks like you have Shopify on this domain saletab

Answer (score 0):

first you need to check your file directory , there is 1 folder " downloader " if this folder is rename then please set name that i mention in quote , and if not available then please download  fresh magento and copy that folder to in your file directory.